# Smoothed density maps for points in using sf within a given boundary in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, smoothing, kernel-density

I'm trying to create a smoothed map for a number of points in R, and I did not find a perfect solution here.

```
library(mapchina)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Create some sample data
sf_beijing = china %>% 
  filter(Code_Province == '11') %>% 
  st_transform(4326)

sf_points = data.frame(
  lat = c(39.523, 39.623, 40.032, 40.002, 39.933, 39.943, 40.126, 40.548),
  lon = c(116.322, 116, 116.422, 116.402, 116.412, 116.408, 116.592, 116.565)
) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

# Plot the boundary for Beijing and the points
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = sf_beijing, fill = NA) + 
  geom_sf(data = sf_points, color = 'red') + 
  theme_test()
```

[image]

In addition, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566685/plotting-a-kernel-map-based-on-points-with-geom-sf/52670671#52670671) to create a smoothed map for `sf` points. The issue for this solution is that the smoothed map is not filled entirely in Beijing's boundary, and some of the smoothed parts go beyond the boundary.

```
ggplot() +
  stat_density_2d(data = sf_points, 
                  mapping = aes(x = purrr::map_dbl(geometry, ~.[1]),
                                y = purrr::map_dbl(geometry, ~.[2]),
                                fill = stat(density)),
                  geom = 'tile',
                  contour = FALSE,
                  alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_sf(data = sf_beijing, fill = NA) + 
  geom_sf(data = sf_points, color = 'red') + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 'magma', direction = -1) +
  theme_test()
ggsave('p1.png', width = 7, height = 8)
```

[image]

My question is: is there a way to create a smoothed map for these points and the smoothed map fills perfectly within the external boundary (no white space and no ``trespass'')?

Comment: perhaps like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53798137/2761575

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I want to propose the following approach. It's quite convoluted and there might be more efficient solutions, but I think it works.

Load packages

```r
library(mapchina)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(spatstat)
#> Loading required package: spatstat.data
#> Loading required package: spatstat.geom
#> spatstat.geom 2.2-2
#> Loading required package: spatstat.core
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> Loading required package: rpart
#> spatstat.core 2.3-0
#> Loading required package: spatstat.linnet
#> spatstat.linnet 2.3-0
#> 
#> spatstat 2.2-0       (nickname: 'That's not important right now') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'
library(ggplot2)
```

Create a polygon and some sample data. Please notice that I set a projected CRS since it's required by `spatstat` package (see below).

```r
sf_beijing = china %>%
  dplyr::filter(Code_Province == '11') %>%
  st_transform(32650)

sf_points = data.frame(
  lat = c(39.523, 39.623, 40.032, 40.002, 39.933, 39.943, 40.126, 40.548),
  lon = c(116.322, 116, 116.422, 116.402, 116.412, 116.408, 116.592, 116.565)
) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  st_transform(32650)
```

Convert points into `ppp` object. Check `?ppp` and references therein for more details.

```r
ppp_points <- as.ppp(sf_points)
```

Convert `sf_beijing` into `owin` + add window to `ppp_points`. Check `?Window` for more details.

```r
Window(ppp_points) <- as.owin(sf_beijing)
```

Plot

```r
par(mar = rep(0, 4))
plot(ppp_points, main = "")
```

[image]

Smooth points

```r
density_spatstat <- density(ppp_points, dimyx = 256)
```

Convert `density_spatstat` into a stars object. Check https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/index.html for more details.

```r
density_stars <- stars::st_as_stars(density_spatstat)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'stars':
#>   method            from
#>   st_crs.SpatRaster sf  
#>   st_crs.SpatVector sf
```

Convert `density_stars` into an `sf` object

```r
density_sf <- st_as_sf(density_stars) %>%
  st_set_crs(32650)
```

Plot

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = density_sf, aes(fill = v), col = NA) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  geom_sf(data = st_boundary(sf_beijing)) +
  geom_sf(data = sf_points, size = 2, col = "black")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

The smoothed values are estimated using the `spatstat` package and they fit the original boundary quite well. Increase the value of `dimyx` if you really need to fill the tiny tiny gaps. Check `?density.ppp` and the references therein for more details.

Comment: If someday you could publish a tutorial of how to do this with a multipolygon sf object would be awesome. Now I am moving to QGIZ  because in R I was not able to create the smooth plot I wanted for some crime variables...

Comment: Hi @JohnM.Riveros, could you please share a reproducible example for the multipolygon case? Even better if you create a new question and you link it here.